# Почему не парсится ajax-ответ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, vkontakte-api

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему такой скрипт выводит результат в консоль:

```
function getData() {
    $.get( "http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?v=5.5", function( data ) {
        var resp = JSON.stringify(data['response']['items']);
      console.log( JSON.parse(resp) );
    }); 
};

getData();
```

, а такой скрипт нет:

```
function getData() {
    $.get( "http://api.vk.com/method/database.getCountries?v=5.5", function( data ) {
        var resp = JSON.parse(data['response']['items']);
      console.log( resp );
    }); 
};

getData();
```

Текст ошибки в консоли:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()

Comment: а зачем пытаться парсить JSON объект? вы же понимаете что `stringify`  и `parse` эт обратные друг другу функции?  и первый код по сути эквивалентен `console.log(data['response']['items'])`, а во втором вы к нему пытаетесь еще и `parse`  приделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр `data`, который вы получаете в случае успешного выполнения запроса, уже содержит корректный объект. Это не строка, ее не надо парсить дополнительно. 
Ответ на запрос, как вы можете увидеть в инструментах разработчика, приходит с установленными заголовками

```
content-type    application/json; charset=utf-8
```

и этого достаточно что бы  jquery автоматически определила тип контента и применила к нему `JSON.parse` прежде чем эти данные поступили в ваш обработчик.

Поэтому повторный вызов излишен, и приводит, как видите к ошибке. Объект с помощью `toString()` приводится в строковый вид, получая сроку `[object Object]`, отсюда и `o` в позиции 1.

Comment: Технологии умнеют!